# Reconstructing the metric on $CP^2$ with special one forms

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, linear-pde, complex-manifolds

I know that $(z_1,z_2)$ are the affine\inhomogeneous coordinates on the complex projective space $CP^2$. Now I have four one forms $(Y_1,Y_2, Y_3, Y_4)$. I want to rewrite the Fubini Study metric on $CP^2$ in terms of the forms $(Y_1,Y_2, Y_3, Y_4)$ .  The expressions for the one forms in terms of $(z1,z2)$ are given below
\begin{split}
&&Y1=\frac{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2}}{(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)(1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)}dz1-\frac{z1\bar{z}_2(-1+\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2})}{(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)(1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)}dz2\\
&&Y2=\frac{|z_2|^2+|z_1|^2\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2}}{(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)(1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)}dz2-\frac{z2\bar{z}_1(-1+\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2})}{(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)(1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)}dz1\\
&&Y_3=-\bar{Y}_1\\ 
&&Y_4=-\bar{Y}_2
\end{split}

I have been able to workout the following relations
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\bar{z}_1 dz_1+\bar{z}_2 dz_2}{1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2} &=\bar{z}_1Y_1+\bar{z}_2Y_2\\
\frac{z_1d\bar{z}_1+z_2 d\bar{z}_2}{1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2}&=-(z_1Y_3+z_2Y_4)
\end{split}
$$
Is there a way to get the relation using the above condition so that I can rewrite the Fubini-Study metric in terms of these forms?
Special Case: To make my question clear let us consider the case $z2=0$. Then we see the relationship reduces to the following
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{ dz_1}{1+|z_1|^2} &=Y_1\\
\frac{d\bar{z}_1}{1+|z_1|^2}&=-Y_3
\end{split}
$$
Taking the product of the above equation gives
$$
\begin{split}
ds^2=\frac{ dz_1d\bar{z}_1}{(1+|z_1|^2)^2}=-Y_1Y_3=Y_1\bar{Y}_1
\end{split}
$$
This is the Fubini Study metric on $CP^1$ with inhomogeneous/affine coordinates $(z_1,z_2)$. I am expecting to rewrite using the forms the Fubini-Study metric on $CP^2$.

Comment: Maybe I am calculating incorrectly, but the left hand side does not appear to be a closed 1-form, so cannot equal the right hand side in an open subset of two complex variables.

Comment: @Ben McKay I have corrected my mistakes and edited the question

Answer (score 3):

My calculation has the exterior derivative of the left hand side being
$$\frac{(1+|z_2|^2)d\bar{z}_1\wedge dz_1 + (1+|z_1|^2)d\bar{z}_2\wedge dz_2 - z_1\bar{z}_2 d\bar{z}_1 \wedge dz_2 -z_2\bar{z}_1 d\bar{z}_2\wedge dz_1}{(1+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)^2}.$$
The right hand side is closed. So the two sides cannot be equal on any open set of any 4-manifold on which $z_1,z_2$ are local complex coordinates and $y_1,y_2$ functions of them.

Comment: Isn't this the Fubini Study form on CP^2 with affine coordinate (z1, z2)

Comment: I worked out the explicit expressions for the one form. The right hand side is not closed now.